# Matrix multiply two lists with a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, matrix-multiplication, worksheet-function

If I have two lists in Excel:

```
X : x1  x2  x3
Y : y1  y2  y3
```

How can I make a 2-dimensional matrix like this?:

```
x1*y1  x1*y2  x1*y3
x2*y1  x2*y2  x2*y3
x3*y1  x3*y2  x3*y3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming X1-X3 is the cells `A1:A3` and Y1-Y3 in `B1:B3`, select a 3x3 range and enter this formula:

```
=A1:A3*TRANSPOSE(B1:B3)
```

Enter it as an array formula, i.e. instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>!

Answer (score 0):

Use `=MMULT(array1,array2)` as an array formula.

for details [see](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/mmult-HP005209181.aspx).